# How to get list of branch_id that is not the same of Max Permissions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

[image: SAMPLE PHOTO]

Attached above is the sample table structure. The table consists of 3 columns of user_id, branch_id, and permission_id.

I have a given **Max Permissions of each user_id**, wherein it consists multiple permissions(permission_id) of certain user_id in branch_id (user's branch permission)

The main problem here is I don't know how to get all branches(branch_id) that are not the same permissions of the given **Max Permissions**.

I've made a query but unfortunately, I can't solve this logical problem.

Here is the query that I've made:

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT branch_id) AS all_branch
    FROM branch_permission_user
    WHERE 
        USER_ID = 18 AND
        permission_id NOT IN (
            SELECT permission_id
            FROM branch_permission_user
            WHERE
                USER_ID = 18 AND
                BRANCH_ID = 39)
```

You'll notice that I've write a specific user_id **(18)** and branch_id **(39)**.
I've made a piece of SQL query to find the branch_id of the max length of each user.

Please help me. Thank you all in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the rows that are not in a list of available permissions for a user, you can use:

```
select bpu.*
from branch_permission_user bpu
where user_id = 18 and
      permission_id not in (1, 2, 3, . . . );  -- list goes here
```

You can count the branches using `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct branch_id)
from branch_permission_user bpu
where user_id = 18 and
      permission_id not in (1, 2, 3, . . . );  -- list goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by getting the branch_id of minimum permission length and using where in clause. If no. of the result is 0, then it is the same.

Here is the SQL query that I've made:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT branch_id) as branch_length
FROM branch_permission_user
WHERE 
    user_id = 18 AND
    permission_id NOT IN (
        SELECT permission_id
        FROM branch_permission_user
        WHERE 
            user_id = 18 AND 
            branch_id = 39 )
```